# How to export revision range through Command line or PowerShell?

Tags: svn

When I export through PowerSshell and Command line interface it gives an error `SVN: E195008: Revision range is not allowed`
when I export up to single revision it works. Anyone have idea about how can I use the following command:

```
svn export -r 78497:78498 "SVN url" "Path" --force
```

Comment: If you can explain what you expect providing a revision range to export to do then I can expand my answer more.

Answer (score 0):

Export doesn't accept revision ranges.  You can specify a single revision which provides you all the files state as of that revision.